# Avahi gtk style provider error/ avahi-daemon won't start

Tags: gtk, daemon, wsl2, mdns, avahi

So, just got a Raspberry Pi, and I'm trying to connect to it via mDNS.
However, when  trying to start avahi-daemon on my WSL2 kali-linux distribution

`sudo service avahi-daemon start`

I get

`Starting Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Daemon: avahi-daemon failed!`

I already installed avahi-daemon avahi-discover avahi-utils libnss-mdns and mdns-scan.

Also, when I run avahi-discover

```
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(avahi-discover:2476): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 09:08:43.802: _gtk_style_provider_private_get_settings: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE (provider) failed
(avahi-discover:2476): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 09:08:43.802: _gtk_style_provider_private_get_settings: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE (provider) failed
(avahi-discover:2476): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 09:08:43.802: _gtk_style_provider_private_get_settings: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE (provider) failed
```

Not sure why this is happening, but I can try connecting to my pi a different way, just was wondering why this wouldn't work so I can fix it for the future. Thank you

Comment: Have you looked at the system logs, then? If something goes wrong with a system service, the relevant messages usually go to syslog. That's either `journalctl -n 100` or `tail -n 100 /var/log/syslog` or something similar. (Also, do you want to use mDNS simply for hostname lookup, or do you need it for service discovery? Windows already has the former.)

Comment: I need it for service discovery, I'm just trying to connect to my raspberry pi headless, so I just need the IP address. I'm trying other methods, I'm just wondering why avahi doesnt work. I checked the logs, but says "No journal entries were found"

Comment: Check the other log locations. Different Linux distributions place them in different spots. (Also, does a raspberry pi actually come with Avahi running by default nowadays? I think they used to have networking inactive by default in the past.)

Answer (score 0):

So, I was looking for the log files (Thank you, user1686) and wondered what would happen if I ran ```sudo avahi-daemon'''. I did it, and found a "failed to contact D-bus error". I realized the dbus daemon wasn't running and started it up. Sure enough, avahi-daemon finally started. Thank you for the help.